# python - calculation inside arguments

Tags: python, multithreading, parameters, arguments, calculation

Can "cur_range + range_nmbr" inside the arguments cause problems?

```
   my_thread = threading.Thread(target=check,args=(cur_range, cur_range + range_nmbr))
        my_thread .start()
        thread_counter += 1
        cur_range += range_nmbr
```

Comment: No. Operators are evaluated first so the final result value of the calculation would be passed as the argument.

Comment: Why would it? Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't cause any problems in your code. Python will first add this two values and then process the rest of the code